# Get-Childitem and brackets [] in path -- or: LiteralPath + Asterisk

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm trying to use a wildcard (*) with `LiteralPath` so that my code works on paths with brackets, too.

At the moment, I don't get errors with my code, but it also won't delete the file(s) in question.

```bsh
$path="f:\test\test[lala] lulu\file.rar"
$remfile=$(get-childitem -LiteralPath $path )
$remove = $remfile.fullname.substring(0,$($remfile.fullname).length -3)
get-childitem $($remove + '*') | remove-item -force
```

With the `remove` line, I strip away the last 3 chars of the name. so far, so good:

```
write-output $remove
F:\test\test[lala] lulu\file.
```

The last line adds an asterisk to the search string and it doesn't give me an error but it deletes nothing, either.

Adding another `LiteralPath` to the last line's GCI gives me errors because the asterisk is not used as a wildcard.

how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a trick.  -filter doesn't understand the brackets as wildcards, even in PS 6.

```
get-childitem -filter file[*] | remove-item -whatif
```

EDIT:  Oh, it's a directory.  How about:

```
 get-childitem -LiteralPath 'F:\test\test[lala] lulu\' -filter file* | remove-item -WhatIf
```

Or, if you were already on the F: drive:

```
get-childitem -filter 'test\test[lala] lulu\file*' | remove-item -WhatIf
```

EDIT:  You can also bring where into this:

```
get-childitem -LiteralPath 'test[lala] lulu' -filter file* | 
where name -notlike *.txt | remove-item -WhatIf
```

Comment: thank you very much, js2010. that helped a lot. i'll rewrite my code a bit so that i only have the path in the literalpath segment and use filter for the files without the last 3 chars. thanks again.

Comment: ok, it gets more complicated. when filter is active, it seems, my "exclude" statements won't work anymore. in the original, i have excludes like -exclude *.txt